# Closure with parameter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, closures

It is a simple question, why are var1 and var2 undefined .

I was trying to learn closures in javascript and added a parameter but not sure why it is undefined.

```
    var closureFunction = function(var1,var2){  
        var privateVar = var1+var2;     

        console.log("Sum of "+ var1 +" and "+ var2+"");     
        return function(){return privateVar;} 
    }();


    console.log(closureFunction(2,3));
```

Comment: You pass none in.

Comment: How can I pass parameters ?

Comment: Don't immediately invoke it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use brackets () after a function, it gets executed immediately.
And in this case you have not passed any parameter there.

It can go two ways.

```
   var closureFunction = function(var1,var2){  
        var privateVar = var1+var2;     

        console.log("Sum of "+ var1 +" and "+ var2+"");     
        return function(){return privateVar;} 
    }(2,3);  //prints 'Sum of 2 and 3'

    console.log(closureFunction()); //prints '5'
```

Or you can pass parameters in steps

```
var closureFunction = function(var1){  

    return function(var2 ){
         console.log("Sum of "+ var1 +" and "+ var2+"");
         return var1 + var2;
     } 
}(2);  //just return a 'closure' function

console.log(closureFunction(3)); //prints 'Sum of 2 and 3 5'
```

or you can execute it later.

```
var closureFunction = function(var1){  

    return function(var2 ){
         console.log("Sum of "+ var1 +" and "+ var2+"");
         return var1 + var2;
     } 
};  

var x = closureFunction(2);  //return a 'closure' function
console.log(x(3)); //prints 'Sum of 2 and 3 5'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the closure once its available.

```js
var closureFunction = function(var1, var2) {
  var privateVar = var1 + var2;

  console.log("Sum of " + var1 + " and " + var2 + "");
  return function() {
    return privateVar;
  }
};


console.log(closureFunction(2, 3)());
```